# Gradle task dependencies: "run integration tests" vs "deploy, run integration tests, kill deployment"

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a somewhat complex deployment task as well as an integration testing task. At the moment, my integration testing task depends on the deployment task. However, I'd like to have a sort of wrapper task for the integration testing task such that I can build a task to just run the integration test against whatever is currently running **and** a task to deploy, run the integration test, and then take down the deployment again.

This is the current state:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: "startWebappNodes") {
  testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

task runIntegrationTests(type: Exec, dependsOn: "integrationTest") {
    commandLine 'docker-compose', 'down'
    doLast {
        println "Integration tests running finished"
    }
}
```

How can I write a task, let's call it `executeIntegrationTest`, that executes the integration test without depending on `startWebAppNodes` and then also have a test that runs `startWebAppNodes`, then `executeIntegrationTest`, then brings down the nodes again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simplier way: use two main tasks for running integrationTest:

- the first one (your current `integrationTest` task) to execute tests in a standalone way (without deploy/shutdown),
- the second one (your current `runIntegrationTests` task) to wrap the first task, and handle the deploy/shutdown nodes.

1) Remove the `dependsOn` dependency between `integrationTest` task and `startWebappNodes`

=> you can execute this `integrationTest` task in a "standalone" way ( *against whatever is currently running* )

```
./gradlew integrationTest
    // execution of dependent task 

  > Task :integrationTest
    // .. test executing...
```

2) Update your `runIntegrationTests` task to make it depends on both `integrationTest` and `startWebappNodes` tasks, and also add a constraint to make `startWebappNodes` execute before `integrationTest`, using `mustRunAfter`

```
task runIntegrationTests(type: Exec) {
    group "test"
    dependsOn startWebappNodes
    dependsOn integrationTest
    commandLine 'docker-compose', 'down'
    doLast {
        println "Integration tests running finished"
    }
}

integrationTest.mustRunAfter startWebappNodes
```

=> when executing task `runIntegrationTests` it will start nodes, execute integration test, then shutdown nodes

```
./gradlew runIntegrationTests
    // execution of dependent task 

  > Task :startWebappNodes

  > Task :integrationTest
    // .. test executing...

  > Task :runIntegrationTests
    Integration tests running finished
```